# ASP.NET control with jQuery. Specific version for control

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Is below how you would use a specific version of jQuery (already previously assigned on a page) in a control and set it back to the previous version for remaining control/s.

I know this is not ideal but the who app will be cleaned up later.

Thanks in advance.

```
<!-- This would be set earlier on the page. Possibly at page level or in a previous control -->
<script type="text\javascript" src='jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>

<!-- This would at the start of the control -->
<script>
var $origJquery = null; //Should be unique var name for the control

if(typeof jQuery != 'undefined')
    $origJquery = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<script type="text\javascript" src='jquery-1.7.2.js'></script>

<script>
var $newJquery = jQuery.noConflict();

//Can use $newJquery here

</script>

<script>
//Set back when finished at end of control
if($origJquery != null)
{
    $ = $origJquery;
    $origJquery = null;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would load the specific (new) version before you load the default version.

```
<script type="text\javascript" src='jquery-1.7.2.js'></script>

<script>

    // Assign it to the new name space
    var $ns = jQuery.noConflict();

</script>
```

Now the jQuery version is assigned to the new namespace. Then

```
<script type="text\javascript" src='jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>
```

the default version is no accessible on the default jQuery namespace ($).

The new component can access its version with $ns('.selector').

In your version, the new namespace is only valid during loading and if your new component does things after loading (on ready), you run into problems.